# Passing string from spinner to second activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building an app in which the first activity contains a spinner with strings "Red", "Yellow", "Blue" and "Green". When the user selects a spinner item, the second activity's background will be that color. I'm having issues with passing that value from the MainActivity class to the Display class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you wonder how to retrieve the spinner value :

```
String pickedColor = yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

In your first Activity, when building intent do something like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("COLOR_KEY", pickedColor);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your second activity :

```
String color = getIntent().getStringExtra("COLOR_KEY");
```

Then do whatever you need :)

Comment: where pickedColor is the selected string? As in parent.getSelectedItem().toString()?

Comment: yup i edited my answer so you get what is `pickedColor`